# Ubuntu - how to setup hot-spot?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm looking for a suitable WiFi nano dongle so as to enable my Linux single board computer (Raspberry Pi) to act as a WiFi hotspot.

I've tried scouring the internet in search of information.

Would the Atheros AR9271 work for this particular application?

Many thanks,

p.s. I'm not looking for shopping advice, just insight on this particular chipset

Answer (score 0):

I recently set up a hotspot on my Ubuntu desktop using `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`, both of which are available for ARM (and Raspberry Pi)

The Atheros 9k chipsets are well supported, so you're in luck! (my card's an AR9485)

Follow this guide and you should be fine: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2009381